# Cocoas2d Get Sprite by CGPoint

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I use the following code to initialize an object

```
CCSprite *gridp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grid.png" 
                                               rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
gridp.position = ccp(x, y);
```

My question is, after I add the object and after the functions return, how can I delete the sprite? I was guessing there would be a get by CGPoint, but I haven't found anything like that. I cannot store references to all of the objects since the game generates a few hundred of these at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

**To remove a child:**

```
[self removeChild:yourSprite cleanup:YES];
```

**To remove by tag:**

*First you need to specify a tag for your sprite:*

```
[self addChild:yourSprite z:0 tag:1];
```

*Then, to remove it:*

```
[self removeChildByTag:1 cleanup:YES];
```

**Like the others said, you would need to write your own function in order to remove a sprite based on it's position.**

Hope this helped,

*~~Tate*

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a sprite just by the position.. unless you write a function that does that, and therefor you need references to your sprites...

You have to add the sprites to a node to display them... and a node always has a reference to all of it's children. You could walk through the children array to remove nodes you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you assign Tag to the Sprite, then it can be removed using

> [self getChildByTag:spriteName]

Answer (score 0):

And to remove a sprite you use [self removeChild:sprite cleanup: YES];